# Comparing histograms without white color included OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, filter, comparison, histogram

Is there a way that compares histograms but for example white color to be excluded and so white color doesn't affect onto the comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White pixels have **Saturation**, `S = 0`. So, it is very easy to remove the white pixels from being counted while creating histogram. Do the following:

- Convert your image from `BGR` to `HSV`
- Then split your `HSV` image into three individual channels i.e. `H`, `S` and `V`
- Then, access each pixel of channel `S` and if the pixel value = 0 (means S = 0) then it mean that it is a white pixel.
- If the pixel is white then do not consider its Hue value to create histogram and if not...then put its hue value into the corresponding bin (normal procedure to build histogram).

**Summary:** you just need to find white pixels by checking their Saturation value, which is `S = 0`.

**PS:** Have a look at this [**link**](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/colortheory/web/hsv.html) to understand the HSV model.