# OpenCV ignore white color while creating and comparing histograms

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing

I want to ignore white color while comparing two histograms. 
I made my code to make white pixels transparent. But how to compare in BGRA format. Or how to convert to HSV without making transparent white again?

I've tried COLOR_CONVERSION BGRA2BGR and then BGR2HSV. But it failed.

Do u have any solutions to compare two images on color histogram without white using C#?

Comment: Well, just do normal histogram with the full image, and remove the single bin for (255,255,255) (white)

Comment: Should I create mask with that? I'm newbie in openCV :) Sorry for my dumb questions

Comment: I dont do openCV so I dont know. But its just seems straightforward. No mask no anything. Just make a histogram and in the return object/array, set the value of the bin that reffers to the white value to zero. Then do normal histogram matching

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23450664/comparing-histograms-without-white-color-included-opencv

Comment: How do you create the histograms? `cv::calcHist`? That takes a mask as a parameter. So instead of adding an alpha channel, create a mask and use that to ignore all the white pixels.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using that method. I will try this solution with mask